# Need to Trigger Glue Job after two or more crawlers completed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-glue, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have three glue crawlers and as soon as they completed successfully I need to trigger Glue job. But three files associated to three crawlers will load into s3 bucket in different times and I have s3 event which in turn triggers lambda and my lambda will trigger associated crawler as soon as file arrives and it is working fine.

I tried two options but still have issue.

- Option 1#

  I have tried glue work flow to use here to trigger Glue job after successful completion of three crawlers, but I got error when add more than two crawlers to workflow trigger. How to solve this?
  Even if we solve that issue, how do we trigger each crawler as soon as file arrives.
- Option 2#

  How to add two or more crawlers success condition in Cloudwatch Events?

[image]